# Create a claim on Wikidata with a specific type of value

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api, wikibase

I am trying to ingest data to a local Wikibase, which I installed following the steps described in https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/. I'm using the [API of wikibase/wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) for the ingestion and it works as expected. For instance, I could create the triple `Q1`, `P1`, `"200"` as explained [here](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbcreateclaim):

```sh
/api.php?action=wbcreateclaim&entity=Q1&property=P1&snaktype=value&value="200"
```

So, I need to specify the type of the value according to [xsd](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#), namely something as following

`Q1 P1 "200"^^xsd:integer`

I'm aware that we can specify the range of a property when we create it (see [API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbeditentity)) by the `datavalue.type` field (see [documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Data_type)). However, in this case, the node always will be `string` and the type of that value is what I want to set (`integer`).

I know that it should be possible, just see one identifier (e.g., [Q27036482](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q27036482.ttl) ) on Wikidata in turtle format. Next, one real example

```
v:67929068efe9dbc374bc4dc78d86121d a wikibase:TimeValue ;
    wikibase:timeValue "2015-09-23T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    wikibase:timePrecision "11"^^xsd:integer ;
    wikibase:timeTimezone "0"^^xsd:integer ;
    wikibase:timeCalendarModel <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727> .
```

Can anyone give me a clue about that? Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. The type is always specified at the property level. Only some type parameters vary between uses. For multilingual strings, the language is specified as “is this Latin?”@en. Time precision is specified as, for example, `/9` or `/11` suffixes, for years and days, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue when wrote the django-wikibase adapter.
The time datatype defined in the wikibase documentation: https://doc.wikimedia.org/Wikibase/master/php/md_docs_topics_json.html

So in your case, without URL-encoding, the get request could look like this:

```
/api.php?action=wbcreateclaim&entity=Q1&property=P1&snaktype=value&value={"time":"+2022-01-19T00:00:00Z","timezone":0,"before": 0,"after":0,"precision":11,"calendarmodel":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727"}
```

Please be sure that property P1 in that case has a "time" data type. And pay attention to the format of the "time" field. Not all wikibase versions have the full support of ISO 8601.